# How to get checked checkbox value which is created dynamically in button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having checkboxes which are created dynamically in page_load event and put it in panel.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in column_ds.Rows)
        {
            column_checkbox = new CheckBox();
            column_checkbox.Text = (string)dr["COLUMN_NAME"];
            columnpanel1.Controls.Add(column_checkbox);
        }
```

now i want the checked check box values in btn_click event.
any ideas?
i tried,

```
columnpanel1.FindControl("column_checkbox");
```

and

```
  CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)FindControl("column_checkbox");
        if (column_checkbox.Checked) { }
        {
            string name = column_checkbox.Text;
        }
```

Comment: use string name = Convert.ToString(column_checkbox.Checked);

Comment: what about panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your comments and answers.

Finally i got by,

```
foreach (Control cb in columnpanel1.Controls)
        {
            if (cb is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox c = (CheckBox)cb;
                if (c.Checked)
                {
                    string s = c.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On click event of button, you can implement below logic.

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var row in columnpanel1.Rows)
   {
       var tempchkBx= row.Controls[0] as CheckBox;
       if(tempchkBx.IsChecked)
       {
         //write your code
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
foreach (DataRow dr in column_ds.Rows)
        {
            column_checkbox = new CheckBox();
            column_checkbox.Text = (string)dr["COLUMN_NAME"];
            column_checkbox.ID = (string)dr["ID"]
            columnpanel1.Controls.Add(column_checkbox);
        }
```

Than you can find control using ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in LINQ:

```
var boxes = columnpanel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c=>c.Checked).ToList();

 foreach(var chk in boxes )
        {
          string s = chk.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case for that to work you need to add an event handler to dynamically added controls in your case

```
checkbox = new CheckBox();
phChecklist.Controls.Add(checkbox);
checkbox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

and then what you need to do in the method

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```